# How to get property values from ancestor controls far away in a complex WPF visual tree, in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tree

For starters, I barely know what I'm doing.

I'd like to reach up to a control that's pretty far away in my visual tree to get a property value from it.  It's a ContentControl and the property is IsTabStop.  I'm in a user control which is heavily re-used in a variety of places with different tree structures.  Since the tree structure is so variable, I don't think I can just use FindAncester with a type of "ContentControl" (can't predict how many intermediate ContentControls are in the tree).

The control I'm looking for is in the DataTemplate used to display an item in an ItemsControl.  Even though there's a unique name, my attempt to snag the property value with an ElementName binding didn't work either.  (It seems to have picked up the wrong value.)

There are also more than one ItemsControl in the picture (meaning, I may or may not be inside a secondary ItemsControl), so I don't think I can use some variant of "." (even if I was smart enough to think of one).

Is there some way I can do this in XAML, or is this just asking XAML to do too much?  Should I be explicitly creating the appropriate Binding in the code-behind?

---

Edit, 27 Apr:

tl;dr: Looks like ElementName is the right approach.  I guess it gets resolved exactly in the way I would have written my procedural code (and in a way similar to how JavaServer Faces does it):  by walking up the tree until we find a scope containing the named element (which is close enough to "walking up the tree until we get a hit" for -government work- hackery).  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/23/of-logical-and-visual-trees-in-wpf.aspx  (Editorial note for Microsoft: why does this piece of info need to be in a blog entry?  Am I supposed to be reading source code?  At least Sun laid it out in a spec.)

I agree I don't need procedural code, but....

Stuff I've tried:

IconsToolsBar.xaml:

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid><Grid><Border><Grid>
    <!-- Fail.  Defaults to true, ignores ancestor values (apparently). -->
    <Button/>
    <!-- Fail.  Snoop reports a binding error (red highlight) -->
    <Button IsTabStop="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsTabStop}"/>
    <!-- Um, well... this seems to work.  Why?  "FormElement" occurs multiple times by virtue of the fact that we're
         in an ItemsControl.
    -->
    <Button IsTabStop="{Binding IsTabStop, ElementName=FormElement}"/>
  </Grid></Border></Grid></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Separate resource file.  Note that this "dictionary" object can occur inside another ItemsControl not shown.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiSelectListDictionaryDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <toolBars:IconsToolBar DataContext="{Binding IconsToolBarController}"/>
      <!-- other stuff -->
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ObsSuggestedDictionaryViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DictionaryPresenter"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DropdownSingleDictionaryDataTemplate}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayFormat}" Value="Vertical"/>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectionType}" Value="Multi Select"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter TargetName="DictionaryPresenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MultiSelectListDictionaryDataTemplate}"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is a 3rd separate file that has a user control that contains objects of various types, including the "dictionary" type above, that we want to display.  Note that this LayoutPart is itself contained in yet another ItemsControl, but I'm not going to lay the tree out that far up, because here is where the data I want lives.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiSelectListDictionaryDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <toolBars:IconsToolBar DataContext="{Binding IconsToolBarController}"/>
      <!-- other stuff -->
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ObsSuggestedDictionaryViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DictionaryPresenter"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DropdownSingleDictionaryDataTemplate}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayFormat}" Value="Vertical"/>
          <Condition Binding="{Binding SelectionType}" Value="Multi Select"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter TargetName="DictionaryPresenter" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MultiSelectListDictionaryDataTemplate}"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

(It's unfortunate that we're calling our objects "dictionaries".  It's "for historical reasons".)

ObsSuggestedDictionaryViewModel is a subclass of a class that has a property that tells us whether we want the thing to be a tab stop or not.

Comment: 1 - what do you want that property for? 2 - post your  current XAML so we can understand what you're  talking about.

Comment: Purpose: Keyboard navigation.  I want a button to be a tab stop but only conditionally, depending on conditions in the view model higher up in the tree.

XAML posting: I would, but (a) it's probably more-or-less proprietary, and (b) it's insanely complex due to teams on two coasts with different visions and management pressure to Just Get It Done. Nasty real-world code.

Comment: then use `DataTemplate.Triggers` and put a `DataTrigger` that binds to whatever properties in the ViewModel, eventually using a `RelativeSource` to find the desired UI Element and refer to it's DataContext. **You don't need procedural code for this.**